# Converting font from WOFF (Web Open Font Format) to a format I can use in MS Word

Tags: conversion, fonts

I have a WOFF file I downloaded from a website that I want to convert for use in Microsoft Word documents and such. Is there any free way to do this? After much searching I have not found a way, so I am turning to Super User for help.

Comment: If you had included the name of the font (or the url of where you found the WOFF file), we might have been able to find a source for TTF or OTF version that wouldn't need conversion and might include more characters.

Answer (score 25):

Yes, the [WOFF format](http://www.w3.org/TR/WOFF/) is a container for the table-based sfnt structure (used by TrueType and OpenType). It adds some meta data to the TTF/OTF font and can also compress the actual font data.

If you want to convert from WOFF to the wrapped TTF/OTF font, you can use the [woff2sfnt-tool](http://people.mozilla.org/~jkew/woff/) created by Jonathan Kew at Mozilla. He provides pre-compiled binaries for the [sfnt2woff-tool](http://people.mozilla.org/~jkew/woff/) (convert from TTF/OTF to WOFF) for OS X and Windows, but not for the woff2sfnt-tool (convert from WOFF to TTF/OTF), so you have to compile from the source. Easily done if you have a working compiler toolchain — just download the source-zip-file and run `make`.

When you have a working woff2sfnt binary, you just do:

```
$ ./woff2sfnt font.woff > font.otf
```

The resulting font is an ordinary TTF/OTF font that you can use, but please note that if you download a WOFF font from a web site, you are supposed to comply with the license of this font. Licensing information can be included in the WOFF meta data.

Comment: woff2sfnt-tool can't find it...

Comment: -1 didn't provide the correct link

Comment: Excuse me? The links I provided (over a year ago) still works. I also clearly state you have to compile the tool yourself. Please read before down voting.

Comment: For Ubuntu Linux and similar systems, the package containing ```woff2sfnt``` and ```sfnt2woff``` is called ```woff-tools```

Comment: link is broken?

Comment: The source code seems to be available on github [wget/sfnt2woff](https://github.com/wget/sfnt2woff). There's also [google/woff2](https://github.com/google/woff2) for working with the `woff2` format. And a python implementation specifically for converting woff to otf [hanikesn/woff2otf](https://github.com/hanikesn/woff2otf). And the [bramstein/sfnt2woff-zopfli](https://github.com/bramstein/sfnt2woff-zopfli) repo mentioned below

Answer (score 4):

Following Erik Tjernlund's link, I downloaded the source and compiled a i386 executable of `woff2sfnt` and `sfnt2woff` for Windows. [You can download it from my Dropbox here.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/901545/woff-code-20090909.zip)

(Note that this works on x86-64 machines as well. In fact, you can't build it for x86-64 because the binary object provided by Jonathan Kew is for the i386 architecture type.)

Comment: cygwin1.dll was not found

Comment: @MuhammadUmer Evidently you need to install Cygwin in order to get it working.

Comment: For those reading with no Cygwin experience, you need cygwin1.dll (from 'cygwin'), cygz.dll (from 'zlib0') and cyggcc_s-1.dll (from 'libgcc1'). Once these are in the same directory it will work fine.

Answer (score 4):

to convert WOFF2 files to ttf on macOS, try

```
brew install fonttools
ttx font.woff
ttx font.ttx
```

`ttx font.woff` will convert your `.woff` file to a `.ttx` file (an XML font file format). Then `ttx font.ttx` will convert the `.ttx` to a `.ttf`.

If the file you get out of `ttx font.ttx` can't be imported you can try dragging `font.ttf` into Font Book, reading what the errors are (click the drop down arrow next to the font name) and fixing them in the `.ttx` file. For example, I had to add a `namerecord`.

---

For batch conversion try

```
for f in *.woff; do ttx $f; done
for f in *.ttx; do ttx $f; done
```

---

I also tried google's woff2 from [this repo](https://github.com/bramstein/homebrew-webfonttools)

```
brew tap bramstein/webfonttools
brew install woff2
woff2_decompress font.woff
```

but that didn't create any `.ttf` or `.otf` files.

---

In the end I googled "fontname otf" and installed that instead.

Comment: Works the same at Ubuntu Linux (20.10): `sudo apt-get install fonttools`, then `ttx font.woff2` and finally `ttx font.ttx`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [FontForge](http://fontforge.org/) to convert it - it is an application that can create and edit font files.

You install it, and then you can right click on the Font file and select 'Properties'. Next to 'Open With' click 'Change', then go to 'Browse':
 [image]

You then need to find the location of the FontForge executable - on Windows 7 64bit it is located here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\FontForge\run_fontforge.exe
```

Once you have opened the font, you ignore most errors about wrong table types and stuff, and click 'Generate Fonts':

Select the save location, and `ttf` or `otf` as the export format. OTF fonts sometimes can have higher quality depending on the font you are importing.

[image]

Fontforge can use a variety of export and imported font types, so it can be used to conver other fonts as well. It is also very useful for making or recreating your own fonts. There is a guide [here](http://designwithfontforge.com/en-US/Introduction.html) with other uses of FontForge.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

i got the woff2sfnt source to compile for windows 10 x64 with the following steps cobbled together from other references (i.e. i'm not claiming any original thought here)

- the mozilla source host appears to be dead, found it here: https://github.com/wget/sfnt2woff... extracted all that to a working folder
- used http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/ as a friendly gcc compiler stack installer
- added  #include <fcntl.h> at the top of woff2sfnt.c under #ifdef WIN32, in addition to io.h already there
- downloaded the zlib source from http://www.zlib.net/ and copied all its root .c and .h files into my working folder
- my gcc command line: `gcc -o woff2sfnt.exe woff2sfnt.c woff.c compress.c uncompr.c deflate.c inflate.c adler32.c inffast.c crc32.c trees.c zutil.c inftrees.c`

i realize this is all very brute force, for i'm a mere C# programmer with the soft underbelly afforded by modern tools, uninitiated with doing gcc the right way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an online font converter, like these:

http://www.fontconverter.org

http://onlinefontconverter.com

http://www.freefontconverter.com

Comment: None of those do batch conversions :/

Comment: Granted it's been quite a few years, but for anyone else who finds this answer the first does not support WOFF and the others are no longer online